# Is it possible in smbus2 to have start and stop conditions as you wish?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, linux-kernel, i2c, smbus

I am using my own processor and SMBUS2 to communicate with an external device over i2c. I have to follow the procedure below to be able to read the IDCODE of the device. Is it possible in smbus2 to have start and stop conditions as you wish?

I2C start | 7-bit I2C ADDR+write bit | slave ACK | 1st byte | slave ACK | 2nd byte | slave ACK | 3rd byte | slave ACK | 4th byte | slave ACK and then **NO stop bit**, rather...

I2C start | 7-bit I2C ADDR+write bit | slave ACK | 1st byte | slave ACK | 2nd byte | slave ACK | 3rd byte | slave ACK | 4th byte | slave ACK | and again **NO stop bit**, rather...

I2C REstart | 7-bit I2C ADDR+**READ** bit | slave ACK | 1st byte | Master ACK | 2nd byte | Master ACK | 3rd byte | Master ACK | 4th byte | Master ACK | **I2C STOP**

My understanding is that the method write_i2c_block_data(...) puts start and stop conditions automatically so it wouldn't quite work to create the flow above. I see the methods read_byte() and write_byte() which maybe just sending bytes without the start and stop, but then what is way to send start and stop bytes. I tried the following but doesn't work.

```
# start
bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDRESS, 0x00) 
wait_for_ack()

for byte in Bytes:
    bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDRESS, byte)
    wait_for_ack()

# stop
bus.write_byte(I2C_ADDRESS, 0xFF)
```

Here wait_for_ack() is something like this,

```
ack = bus.read_byte(I2C_ADDRESS)
if ack == 0x00:
    print("ACK received.")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second I2C start be an I2C REstart?

Comment: I think you should be able to chain several I2C messages with repeated starts using the `.i2c_rdwr()` method.

Comment: @IanAbbott actually in the datasheet, the second one still said to be start. I can try chaining, is it going to be like this: bus.i2c_rdwr(write, write, read)?

Comment: Yes, but I guess you want the two writes to be different? Something like bus.i2c_rdwr(write1, write2, read).

Comment: yes right, it should be two different writes. Do you know the maximum length of data (in let's say write2) the method bus.i2c_rdwr can take?

Comment: Individual messages in the transfer are not allowed to exceed 8192 bytes by the user-space I2C device interface. There may also be length restrictions imposed by the I2C controller hardware. The I2C controller hardware may also have other restrictions on the number and type of message in each transfer, but I think the I2C controllers in the Raspberry Pi are quite permissive.

Comment: This might seem off topic, but I wanted to know if is there is any OS/library file that can be modified to allow more than 8192 bytes The reason I wasn't using .i2c_rdwr() was because of this limitation. That's why I was asking in my question how to manually send start and stop bits.

Comment: The 8192 limit is imposed by the driver for the userspace /dev/i2c-* device files, so you would need to bypass that somehow. Options include writing a kernel-mode driver for the I2C client device, or use the "pigpio" library to bit-bang some GPIO lines.

Answer (score 0):

Like Ian commented, the way to do it is to use the .i2c_rdwr() method. Here is an example,

```
write1 = i2c_msg.write(I2C_ADDRESS, list1)
write2 = i2c_msg.write(I2C_ADDRESS, list2)

num_bytes = 4
read = i2c_msg.read(I2C_ADDRESS, num_bytes)

bus.i2c_rdwr(write1, write2, read)
data = list(read)
print(data)
```

I was also hoping to find a way to send start and stop condition manually so that I can program the device over I2C from a file. For that I guess I have to do just do some bit-banging.